# Manipulation of objects in angularjs/javascript

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have the following data inside my script.js:

`$scope.reports = [{
        departuredate: "2015-2-27",
        routeline: "PASAY - CAGAYAN",
        seatingtypescode: "ABS",
        tickettripcode: "3",
        tripcodetime: "16:30:00"
    }, {
        departuredate: "2015-2-27",
        routeline: "PASAY - CAGAYAN",
        seatingtypescode: "ABS",
        tickettripcode: "3",
        tripcodetime: "16:30:00"
    },{
        departuredate: "2015-2-27",
        routeline: "PASAY - CAGAYAN",
        seatingtypescode: "ABS",
        tickettripcode: "3",
        tripcodetime: "16:30:00"
    },{
        departuredate: "2015-3-1",
        routeline: "Cavite-Laguna",
        seatingtypescode: "ABS",
        tickettripcode: "4",
        tripcodetime: "16:30:00"
    }, {
        departuredate: "2015-3-1",
        routeline: "Cavite-Laguna",
        seatingtypescode: "ABS",
        tickettripcode: "4",
        tripcodetime: "16:30:00"
    },{
        departuredate: "2015-3-2",
        routeline: "Earth-Heaven",
        seatingtypescode: "ABS",
        tickettripcode: "5",
        tripcodetime: "16:30:00"
    }];`

I want to achieve an output which looks like this:

`{
   3:{
       2015-2-27: 3,
       2015-2-28: 0,
       2015-3-1:  0,
       2015-3-2:  0,
       2015-3-3:  0,
       routeline: "PASAY - CAGAYAN"
     },
   4:{
       2015-2-27: 0,
       2015-2-28: 0,
       2015-3-1:  1,
       2015-3-2:  0,
       2015-3-3:  0,
       routeline: "Cavite-Laguna"
     }
   5:{
       2015-2-27: 0,
       2015-2-28: 0,
       2015-3-1:  0,
       2015-3-2:  1,
       2015-3-3:  0,
       routeline: "Earth-Heaven"
     }
 }`

The `3`, `4`, `5` means `tickettripcode` at `$scope.reports`. The dates is the range of date entered by the user. I want to do is to count the number of departuredate in certain tickettripcode.

For example, In `tickettripcode:3` there are 3 same dates(2015-2-27).In `tickettripcode:4` there are 2 same dates(2013-3-1).In `tickettripcode:4` there is only one date(2013-3-2). If there is no departuredate in that given date the value should return `0` as you can see above.

I have done a code but I get the wrong output because it prints all `0`. Just like this:

`{
   3:{
       2015-2-27: 0,
       2015-2-28: 0,
       2015-3-1:  0,
       2015-3-2:  0,
       2015-3-3:  0,
       routeline: "PASAY - CAGAYAN"
     },
  }`

What is the wrong I did. Any help? Thanks very much.

My plunker link is :http://plnkr.co/edit/excSfosrSHUFqF5vDFEO?p=preview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
  var details = {};

  angular.forEach($scope.reports, function (report) {
    if (!details[report.tickettripcode]) {
      details[report.tickettripcode] = {};
      details[report.tickettripcode].routeline = report.routeline;
    }

    angular.forEach(pushDatesInside, function (el) {
      if (typeof details[report.tickettripcode][el.date] === 'undefined') {
        details[report.tickettripcode][el.date] = 0;
      }
    });

    details[report.tickettripcode][report.departuredate] += 1;
  });
```

[Example](http://plnkr.co/edit/IbI6Au5CRXCQI4RSOx10?p=preview)

Answer (score 1):

You reset your `map[pushDatesInsideValue]` with 0 at the end. Check this link (forked from yours):

http://plnkr.co/edit/VESbDZNvaSR9JqXLbX8b?p=preview